# Send transactional text messages from Elastic Beanstalk app using SNS - Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sns

I am trying to send text messages from my Elastic Beanstalk server application, but I keep getting {"Error":{"message":null,"code":404,... }. I followed the code in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/sns-examples-sending-sms.html#sending-sms-publishsms), but I still can't get it to work.

I followed this [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvUdqXI-s7g&fbclid=IwAR1c04a5XpPIgJXB0pMhw6eri8ZlcMJs8asHZDJRCrTp7USeI7p_GsAcWqI) and I am able to send messages from my local development environment, but can't seem to be able to replicate this for my server app. In that tutorial the presenter creates an IAM group and an IAM user and the keys are saved in an .env folder, which I imagine is what makes things work.

I have also granted my Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instances full access to SNS using IAM.

Can someone please explain to me how I can replicate this in my server app? Or how can I send transactional text messages from a node.js/express server?

This is my code:

```
//we have to use us-east-1 because sending texts is not allowed in us-east-2
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

var params = {
    Message: "This is a test",
    PhoneNumber: '+' + "phoneNumberGoesHere",
    MessageAttributes: {
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': "app name goes here"
        }
    }
};

var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31'}).publish(params).promise();

publishTextPromise.then(
    function (data) {
        console.log("Message sent successfully...... ", JSON.stringify({ MessageID: data.MessageId }))
        
    }).catch(
        function (err) {
            console.log("Error sending Text Message...... ", JSON.stringify({ Error: err }))
        });
```

Comment: Could you paste your code in the question itself? Will be helpful in checking the exact problem.

Comment: I just updated the question to include the code... thanks!

Comment: I suspect there is something wrong with the SenderID. Are you sure you are passing the correct value in the SenderID key? 

Just for debugging, can you try to send the SMS without the MessageAttributes key?

Comment: Still the same error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was add the right endpoint and region to this line, now it works perfectly!

```
var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31', endpoint: 'http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', region: 'us-east-1' }).publish(params).promise();
```

and as @Raman Damodar Shahdadpuri mentioned, I needed to remove the .SenderID portion. This is the final code:

```
var params = {
    Message: "This is a test of text messaging",
    PhoneNumber: '+' + 'phone number goes here',
    MessageAttributes: {
        'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
            'DataType': 'String',
            'StringValue': "Transactional"
        }
    }
};

var publishTextPromise = new AWS.SNS({ apiVersion: '2010-03-31', endpoint: 'http://sns.us-east-1.amazonaws.com', region: 'us-east-1' }).publish(params).promise();

publishTextPromise.then(
    function (data) {
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ MessageID: data.MessageId }));
    }).catch(
        function (err) {
            res.end(JSON.stringify({ Error: err }));
        });
```